# How I can combine log entries based on the second column?

Tags: c++

So I have email.log file(limited example):

```
2021-04-30T23:55:00.127629  886715E6D6C9D4FB    status=rejected
2021-04-30T23:55:00.791921  F8F63278A6A3AD87    from=<sarah.smith@example.com>
2021-04-30T23:55:01.470432  418512384DDDD2C6    from=<robert.rodriguez@example.com>
2021-04-30T23:55:01.697902  0D8760D4ADAB456D    message-id=<696b66ea-f493-4ba2-9e8a-553bd03b7d37@2PPZOR2ULU>
2021-04-30T23:55:01.736492  0D8760D4ADAB456D    from=<william.smith@example.com>
2021-04-30T23:55:02.043100  0D8760D4ADAB456D    to=<william.davis@example.com>
2021-04-30T23:55:02.842802  EC5AD35BADC381F9    client=10.2.38.215
2021-04-30T23:55:03.132660  2AB0E95297136E70    client=2001:db8::8f75:20e2:c47f
2021-04-30T23:55:03.550296  BAB22895DB867DFF    status=sent
2021-04-30T23:55:04.392986  5BE423F6370D1D1B    client=10.38.217.222
2021-04-30T23:55:04.661467  5D11914582F8C85A    client=2001:db8::7bbb:6743:c8c5
2021-04-30T23:55:05.306358  E2E8D917BB751176    message-id=<da3d4d7c-643c-4a15-989a-3cd6269030f4@30Q7E75V7B>
2021-04-30T23:55:05.872830  F8F63278A6A3AD87    to=<patricia.garcia@example.com>
2021-04-30T23:55:06.272336  F8F63278A6A3AD87    status=sent
2021-04-30T23:55:06.716495  C7CC8201A67C8E52    from=<thomas.wilson@example.com>
2021-04-30T23:55:07.056882  5BE423F6370D1D1B    message-id=<d5db8bc8-871e-48de-9e64-e23fca0c0134@56WZW5K1C2>
2021-04-30T23:55:07.113379  0D8760D4ADAB456D    status=sent
2021-04-30T23:55:07.370491  5D11914582F8C85A    message-id=<b041aedf-07ec-4e67-9a1a-e9f23a6ab434@82AZ76YJPI>
2021-04-30T23:55:07.732459  2AB0E95297136E70    message-id=<c948f7eb-144c-4688-b122-1191eea2cb29@4Q1QAJ0BLI>
2021-04-30T23:55:08.608998  C1D805D68377D513    to=<karen.smith@example.com>
2021-04-30T23:55:08.782778  418512384DDDD2C6    to=<jessica.jones@example.com>
2021-04-30T23:55:09.383173  E2E8D917BB751176    from=<barbara.rodriguez@example.com>
2021-04-30T23:55:09.676896  33DD2B20F2AB9262    status=sent
2021-04-30T23:55:10.157677  452FAD67C2867C47    client=10.38.217.222
2021-04-30T23:55:11.064902  C7CC8201A67C8E52    to=<patricia.jones@example.com>
2021-04-30T23:55:11.709673  E2E8D917BB751176    to=<richard.garcia@example.com>
2021-04-30T23:55:12.667447  EC5AD35BADC381F9    message-id=<b2fd4dac-2513-4895-ac84-3c68ecabc3ec@U83K85L7HK>
```

I started with reading from file to struct vector and now I need to combine events based on sessionid(column 2). Events may be happening in parallel and overlapping. Incomplete sessions (missing any of the fields) should be ignored. How I can do this?

So far my code look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;


struct Session
{
    string time;
    string sessionid;
    string other;
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& input, Session& session);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, Session& session);
};

istream& operator>>(istream& input, Session& session)
{
  input >> session.time;
  input >> session.sessionid;
  input >> session.other;
  return input;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, Session& session)
{
  output << session.time;
  output << session.sessionid;
  output << session.other;
  return output;
}

int main()
{
  vector<Session> session;
  vector<Session> complete_session;
  Session record;

  ifstream read("email.log");
  while (read >> record)
  {
    session.push_back(record);
  }
  read.close();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can parse your entries and store them in a `map`. To parse them you can split the strings if their format is simple, or use regex for more complex pattern.

Comment: Please use `std::getline` to read line-based input, then construct a `std::istringstream` to do basic formatted input from that line.

Comment: Assuming your `operator>>` works correctly, it's easy: `std::map<std::string, std::vector<Session> >`. Then use `sessionid` as a key. You can can also wrap it in another class to avoid direct operations on `std::map` primitive.

Comment: @pptaszni Thanks for help. Can u help how to read from file with this method? What I have to change in my code?

Comment: Mmm nothing. Just insert your `Session`s in the map like you did with vector. `mySessionMap[record.sessionid].push_back(record)`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at  Also consider other suggestions and improve your input operators by using `std::getline`.

Comment: @pptaszni Thanks! Maybe I should delete vecter and parse it into map. Or vector is neccesary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will write a quick answer, because comments discussion is getting too long. Assuming your `operator>>` is working correctly, you could easily combine your log entries using `std::unordered_map` (faster, but elements are not sorted) or `std::map` (slower, but your map entries will be sorted by `sessionid`). For a quick example you can modify your main like this:

```
int main()
{
  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<Session> > mySessionMap;
  Session record;
  std::ifstream read("email.log");
  while (read >> record)
  {
    mySessionMap[record.sessionid].push_back(record);
  }
  for (const auto& [sessionId, sessions] : mySessionMap)  // c++17 allows us to use structured binding here
  {
    std::cout << "sessionId: " << sessionId << std::endl;
    for (const auto& session : sessions)
    {
      std::cout << session << std::endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Note that you don't need to explicitly create an empty vector when accessing the map with a new key, because [operator[]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) already does it for you if the key does not exist.

You might also consider making your `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Session& session)` a bit more robust by checking if the extracted data is in the expected format.

In `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, const Session& session)` you should use const reference for the second argument to allow printing const objects.

If something is unclear, take a look at [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), everything is nicely explained with examples.

Comment: Thanks you helped me a lot. Can u tell me how I can access first and last element of session time? I need to calculate duration.

Comment: You can use [std::min_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) with lambda that compares min elements of each vector. E.g. `std::min_element(m.begin(), m.end(), [](const auto& l, const auto& r) { return *std::min_element(l.second.begin(), l.second.end()) < *std::min_element(r.second.begin(), r.second.end()); });`